# Preprocessor definitions not carried across premake includes

Tags: c++, preprocessor, premake

I have 3 projects in premake:
Project A (static library):

```
project "A"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C++"
    staticruntime "on"

    files
    {
        "src/**.h",
        "src/**.cpp",
        
        "include/**.h"
    }

    includedirs
    {
        "include"
    }

    defines
    {
        "STATIC_DEFINE"
    }
```

In the dll.h file, inside Project A I have:

```
#ifdef STATIC_DEFINE
#pragma message("Static Define")
#else 
#pragma message("No Static Define")
#endif
```

The other two projects are:

```
project "B"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C++"
    staticruntime "on"
    
    files
    {
        some project files, one of them includes dll.h
    }

    links
    {
        "A"
    }
```

```
Project "C"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"
    staticruntime "on"

    files
    {
        again, project files, one includes dll.h
    }

    links
    {
        "B"
    }
```

there is one final premake file which includes them all

```
workspace "Workspace"
    architecture "x86_64"
    startproject "C"

include "libs/A"
include "libs/B"
include "C"
```

This is not the actual code in my premake files, they are kind of bloated and I judged pseudocode would be enough to explain the problem and fix it, if necessary I can edit the question and add the full premake files and project structure.

What I would expect is for `C` to have `STATIC_DEFINE` defined, since it includes `B` which includes `A` which defines the macro, but the output is as follows:

```
Build started(A):
Static Define
Build started(B):
No Static Define
Build started(C)
No Static Define
```

Again, this is not the full output since it is a full application which has quite a few files, and most of it is not relevant to the question, but I can provide it if needed

I tried adding the

```
defines 
{
    "STATIC_DEFINE"
}
```

to `Project B`, and then it appeared in the output for that `Project B` but not for `Project C`
only when I add the definition to all 3 premake files does it work

Any help to do this without adding the definitions to the premake files would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It seems each project settings are for that project only, not set globally for the entire workspace. How about adding the global macros to the top-level premake file instead?

Comment: I would prefer to avoid that, as in the application the `STATIC_DEFINE` macro is only useful for one individual library out of many others, so it feels strange for it to be a global macro when the only files it affects are that of `Project A`

Comment: *"one of them includes dll.h"*. headers in `files` are mostly unneeded for **build** (but their presences allow to display them in IDE). buildoptions apply to translation units (source files), not to header files.

Comment: True, let me rephrase, one of them includes a .cpp which includes dll.h, which is what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
defines { "STATIC_DEFINE" }
```

is at `project "A"` scope and so only applies to `project "A"`.

There are not ([yet?](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/issues/1346)) usage to "inherit" from some properties (`includedir`, `links`, `defines`).

You might create Lua function for that:

```
function UseA()
    defines { "STATIC_DEFINE" }
    includedirs { "include" }
    links {"A"}
end
```

and then

```
project "B"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C++"
    staticruntime "on"
    
    files
    {
        -- some project files
    }

    useA()
```

Comment: Thank you, that is precisely what I wanted to know, it is kind of weird that its not inherited bu thanks anyway

Comment: It is also common to have `DLL_IMPORT`/`DLL_EXPORT` defines than should NOT be inherited. So it would require a special syntax to choose what is inherited or not anyway.